# How to create a bash script that every 5 minutes insert a record in a log file?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am very new into bash scripting and I need to create a simple script that every 5 minutes insert the date and time into a log file and save it.

What can I do to do it? From what can I start?

Comment: search cron. this is a dup. delete it

Comment: @AndreaNobili did one of the solutions work for you?

Comment: @tgkprog, cron is _a_ solution, but not the _only_ solution (as you can see from the accepted answer).

Comment: using sleep is an option for nearly every job that uses cron. its not a good solution. and am sure its mentioned if you search cron or scheduled jobs. That fact is reflected by the down vote (not mine btw) and the flag for dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date` command will output the current date and time. You can append the output of a command to a file with `>>`. Finally, `sleep` will pause a script for a specified amount of seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    date >> /path/to/the/logfile/dates.log
    sleep 300
done
```

The `date` command also provides options to modify the format of the output, if the optionless output does not suit your needs.

Alternatively, you could issue

```
crontab -e
```

and add the line

```
 */5 * * * * date >> /path/to/the/logfile/dates.log
```

Of course, you can use any name for your logfile, `dates.log` is just the placeholder I used.

Answer (score 1):

Write the bash script that does what you want and add the script to cron and set it to run every 5min.